# How to subtract value from the label?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, subtraction

I have three labels. I want to subtract two labels and put the result in the third label.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Get the texts from both textboxes
    var txt1 = document.getElementById("addition").value;
    var txt2 = document.getElementById("investplan").value;
    //Substract that
    var res = parseInt(txt1) - parseInt(txt2);
    //Set the value to your div
    document.getElementById("subtraction").innerHtml = res;
});
```

```html
<label id="investplan">23940</label>
<label id="addition">138790</label>
<label id="subtraction"></label>
```

Comment: `.value` should be `.textContent`

Comment: Also , `innerHtml` should be `.innerHTML`

Comment: Now getting NaN before subtraction.

Comment: Working fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/w5h1Lepf/) .

Comment: @Swati what if both values (investplan, addition) are dynamic.

Comment: Didn't understood . Please elaborate .

Comment: I have a multiplication of range slider and input field. Their addition of all multiplication is getting in the ids of (investplan, addition).  Values are changing dynamically. I don't know but getting NaN using your jsfiddle code from these comment.

Comment: @AnupamMistry Please ask this additional question as a separate question. You may then paste a link to the new question's URL as a comment here (i.e. directly below this comment) @ Swati.  That way Swati can be rewarded for his answer to your new question, and you will have additional people (new viewers) able to assist as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few pointers:

1. You are mixing up jQuery and pure javascript. `$(document).ready()` is jQuery - you must include the jQuery library. I substituted the pure JS equivalent. ALSO `.val()` is how you read a value in jQuery (which is what you may have been thinking with `.value`), whereas in pure JS you probably want `.innerText` or `.textContent` or `.innerHTML`
2. It is `.innerHTML` not `.innerHtml`
3. Use Divs or Spans instead of label tag. *The label tag is intended to group a clickable control (eg a radio button) with some additional text, so that clicking on the text fires the radio button control.*

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',() => {
    //Get the texts from both textboxes
    var txt1 = document.getElementById("addition").innerText;
    var txt2 = document.getElementById("investplan").innerText;
    console.log(txt1);
    //Substract that
    var res = parseInt(txt1) - parseInt(txt2);
    console.log(res);
    //Set the value to your div
    document.getElementById("subtraction").innerHTML = res;
});
```

```html
<label id="investplan">23940</label>
<label id="addition">138790</label>
<label id="subtraction"></label>
```

Reference:

https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-dom/javascript-page-load-events/

Answer (score 0):

Use [textContent property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_textcontent.asp). The code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Get the texts from both textboxes
    var txt1 = document.getElementById("addition").textContent;
    var txt2 = document.getElementById("investplan").textContent;
    //Substract that
    var res = parseInt(txt1) - parseInt(txt2);
    //Set the value to your div
    document.getElementById("subtraction").innerHTML = res;
})
```

Comment: textContent isn't a method...it is a property